# PHP header() called via AJAX not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm new to web development.

Right now I'm working on a login feature on a site. I used Javascript/AJAX to fetch the username and password and send it to a PHP file for verification on the MYSQL database. That's what I'm about to make.

My question is why can't the header() function working properly? I want after the user login she is redirected to the profile page (profile.php)

Here's snippet of the PHP (login.php):

```
$query = "SELECT * from user WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = md5('$pass');";
$ret = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(!$ret) {
    $msg = "Invalid query " . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $msg .= "Whole query " . $query;
    die($msg);
}

$userid = -1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret)) {
    $userid = $row["ID"];
}

$cnt = mysql_num_rows($ret);
if($cnt == 1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $userid;
    $_SESSION["uname"] = $uname;
    echo "You have logged in successfully!";
    header("Location: profile.php");
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username/Password";
}
```

And here's for the Javascript (an AJAX function):

```
var obj;
    var url = "login.php";
    var params = "uname=" + document.getElementsByName("uname")[0].value + "&pass=" + document.getElementsByName("pass")[0].value;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Major browsers
        obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        obj.open("POST",url,true); 
        obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        obj.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        obj.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(obj.readyState == 4) {
                if(obj.status == 200) {
                    // success
                } else {
                    alert("Problem in returned data" + "Error status=" + obj.status);
                }
            }
        }
        obj.send(params);
```

Comment: the XMLHttpRequest object has a property `onload`, so you don't have to check the status and readystate :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the redirect will work with AJAX. This is what will happen:

1. AJAX request is sent to `login.php`
2. `login.php` sends back a header with `Location: profile.php`
3. The browser then redirects and fetches `profile.php`
4. The results of `profile.php` is then passed to your XMLHttpRequest Object.

A way to get the AJAX response to redirect your page is to do this:

- The response from `login.php` returns a JSON response containing the status code (302 or 301) and the location to redirect to.
- The response itself has a status code of 200 (successful).
- The process the JSON response and check the status code for 302 or 301 and redirect to the location.

Comment: Did you mean that I have to do the redirection on the Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You need to take out the echo statement before header(). Header won't work if anything has been output to the browser before it is called.

Here's the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) on that.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening exactly?

After `header()` is called in php, php still executes the rest of the script unless you stick an `exit;` after the `header()` call. This is only if you don't want to execute the rest of `login.php`

Comment: weirdly it open a pop up window displaying the HTML script for the login page (another page called index.php) . And for the login.php that's the last line on the code so I don't think exit is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can one thing replace your code `header("Location: profile.php");` by `echo "window.location.href='profile.php';` and replace your success function as

```
     if(obj.status == 200) {
         eval(obj.responseText);
     }
```

Thats it. now a response will be evaluated by script and will redirect your page on profile.php