# Header in PHP not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In this program I was making a PHP file with header set to google.co.in. Let us see the code

```
<?php
session_start();
$status=$_POST['input'];

    if (isset($status)) {

        header('Location: http://google.co.in/');
    } 

?>
```

and I have a another file having javascript, Let us have a look to that

```
<?php
session_start();
echo time();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(this).mousemove(function(){

                $.post('logout.php',{input: 1});
                //window.location.href="logout.php"
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>we are on the main_session</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that when I am running this on my localhost I am not being redirected to google.co.in instead in firebug it shows 302 error. But when I am using the window.location.href syntax which I have commented in my code than I am being redirected to google.co.in. Please tell me what is the problem behind this.

Comment: you have commented the redirect code

Comment: yes.....i have commented it

Comment: please uncomment it to redirect successfully

Comment: Are you sure `$status` is set? Put `var_dump($status);` after you set it - what's the value?

Comment: 302 - by definition - is in the 3xx class which are not an error (compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The defined meaning is *Redirect* which is what you're trying to do so I don't understand why you say this is an error.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be redirected **do** use
`window.location.href="logout.php"` or simply `window.location="logout.php"`

instead of  `$.post()` because post retrieves the content of the target webpage while window.location redirects you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$.post` is an AJAX method not a redirect technique. Much clearly, `$.post` is used when you need to get any content from another page and not to redirect. So the solution is use `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SCRIPT:

```
$.post('logout.php',{input: 1} , function(res){
   location.href="logout.php";
});
```

PHP FILE

```
<?php
session_start();
$status=$_POST['input'];

    if (isset($status)) {
        // destroy session or cookies
        // return true
    } 

?>
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think redirects work with ajax methods. Since you are calling $.post() ajax method it sends an XHR request and wait for the server response. Better solution is to use window.location in Java script.

Refer to following post for more details here
[PHP header() called via AJAX not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851792/php-header-called-via-ajax-not-working-properly)