# header() printing to console and not redirecting

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect to a different page but nothing is happening. The page never changes and the html of the page I'm trying to redirect to is displaying in the console. Is there any reason for this?

code:

```
if($bExisitngUser){
/*
 * Set of variables for existing user
 */
 $sUserName = $_POST['sUserName'];
 $sPassword = $_POST['sPassword'];
 $bRememberMe = $_POST['bRememberMe'];

$queryResults = makeLoginRequest('user', $sUserName, $sPassword);
  if($queryResults !== null){
      header('Location: http://www.google.com');
      exit();
  } else{
      header('Location: ../../../ProfilePortal/php/profile.php');
      exit();
  }
}

function conn($sQuery){
    $sMessage = '';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','myvyn') or die('unable to connect!');
    if($db->connect_errno){
        $message = $db->connect_error;
    } else{
        if($db->query($sQuery)){
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            for($aResult = array(); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $aResult[] = $row);
            //print_r($aResult);
            return $row;
        } else{
            $sMessage = $db->error;
            return $sMessage;
        }
    }
}

function makeLoginRequest($table, $id, $pwd){
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `email` = '" . $id . "' AND `password` = '" . $pwd . "'";
    $result = conn($sQuery);
    if(!isset($result)||!defined("$result")||empty($result)||is_null($result)){
        return null;
    } else{
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Working under the assumption that the coding is following correctly. The first if statement above is located in a separate php file from the rest and none of this code is in the index.php file directly. I also am not echoing or printing anything in any of these documents.

This is literally what's in the console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
   'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en_US' xml:lang='en_US'>
 <head>
  <title>MyVyn</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&library=places'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/profile/banner.css' type='text/css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/profile/profile.css' type='text/css'/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id='banner'>   <div id="searchBarWidget">
        <form method="post">
            <input id="inputSearch" name="Query" type="text" placeholder="Search places, users, and area codes"/>
            <input id="submitSearch" name="Search" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="homeButtonContainer">
        <a id="homeButton" >Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="profileButtonContainer">
        <a id="profileButton" >Profile</a>
    </div>
    <div id="settingsContainer">Settings
        <div id="settingsMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>settings</li>
                <li>report problem</li>
                <li>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li>help</li>
                <li>logout</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftContainer">
        <div id="block1" class="block">
            <label id="fullName"></label>
            <div id="placeHolder"></div>
            <!---<img src="http://placehold.it/373x235"></img>--->
        </div>
        <div id="block2" class="block">
            <div id="fullGroupingContainerStyle1">
                <div id="uaGroup" class="groupBoxView">
                    <div id="AUContainer" class="Container">
                        <label class="labelStyle1"># of Admired Users</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="avGroup" class="groupBoxView">
                    <div id="AVContainer" class="Container">
                        <label class="labelStyle1"># of Admired Venues</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="aGroup" class="groupBoxView">
                    <div id="AContainer" class="Container">
                        <label class="labelStyle1"># of Admirers</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="RAgroup">

                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="block3" class="block">
            <div id="questionContainer">
                <div class="question">
                    <label id=""> question 1: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <label id=""> question 2: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <label id=""> question 3: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <label id=""> question 4: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <label id=""> question 5: </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="answerContainer">
                <div class="answer">
                    <label id="answerOne"> answer 1 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <label id="answerTwo"> answer 2 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <label id="answerThree"> answer 3 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <label id="answerFour"> answer 4 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <label id="answerFive"> answer 5 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContainer">
        <div id="block4" class="block">
            <div id="status">
                <textarea id="writeNote" col="100" rows="2"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input id="submitNote" type="submit" value="Post"></input>
                <span id="noteCharCount" class="noteCharCount">34</span>
                <span id="noteCharCountLabel" class="noteCharCount">Available char:&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="block5" class="block">
            <div id="feed"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "console" and what exactly it's printing there.

Comment: I'm referring to the console location in the debugger for the browser.

Comment: I'm not quite clear how a header appears in the browser's debug console. Please show us *exactly* what you're getting. Random guess: you're doing the request via AJAX...!?

Comment: You were correct about the AJAX call being the reason it was printing to console. I had a console.log() there for the results. But even after taking it out, the page doesn't redirect. It did stop printing to console though.

Comment: I figured out that header() won't work with ajax call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851792/php-header-called-via-ajax-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

please try to use use **ob_clean() function** at starting of your script
This function discards the contents of the output buffer.