# Fail using AJAX in a PHP OOP Login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop, pdo

i'm trying to make a OOP Login with ajax, but when I run it I can not get the session started or redirected to the "Directivo.php" page, i don't get any output, where should I start looking?

bdcon.php This is my database connection code

```
<?php
class Conexion extends mysqli{
private $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
private $DB_USER = 'root';
private $DB_PASS = '';
private $DB_NAME = 'bdhtav2';  
public function __construct(){
   parent:: __construct($this->DB_HOST, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS, $this->DB_NAME);
   $this->set_charset('utf-8');
   $this->connect_errno ? die('Error en la conexion'. mysqli_connect_errno()) :
   $M = 'Conectado Correctamente';
   echo $M;
}
}
?>
```

classuser.php Here I do the class that defines the operation of the login

```
<?php
require "bdcon.php";
session_start();
class Users
{
   public $user;
   public $pass;

   public function __construct($usuario, $contraseña)
   {
       $this->user=$usuario;
       $this->pass=$contraseña;
   }
   public function login()
   {
        $db = new Conexion();

    $sql = "SELECT * from user where username = ".$this->user." and password = ".$this->pass;                       $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($count == 1 && !empty($row)){
        $_SESSION["USERNAME"] = $row["username"];
        header('location: directivo.php');
    }else{
        echo"Error";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

acceso.php Here the inputs are filled and is sent through AJAX to "logeo.php"

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title> Log-In </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!--Insentar navbar -->
   <div class="container" style="margin-top:15%;">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-7">
               <H1 align="center">Inicio de Sesión</H1>
               <h4 align="center">Directivos</h4>
               <div class="input-group mb-3">
                   <div class="input-group-prepend">
                       <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Nombre de Usuario</span>
                   </div>
                   <input type="text" id="user1" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
           </div>
               <div class="input-group mb-3">
                   <div class="input-group-prepend">
                       <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Contraseña</span>
                   </div>
                   <input type="text" id="pass1" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
           </div>
           </div>
           <button type="button" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Iniciar Sesión</button>
           <span id="Mensaje"></span>

       <div class="col"></div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <script>




$(document).ready(function(){

function getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        $('#Mensaje').html(msg);
}

   $('#enviar').click(function(){
    var user1 = $('#user1').val();
    var pass1 = $('#pass1').val();

     $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"logeo.php",
       data:{user:user1,pass:pass1},
       dataType:"html",
       success: function(response){
           $("#Mensaje").val(response.responseText);
           alert("Ya puedes dormir");
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, exception){
           getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
       }
       });
   });
});


 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

logeo.php Here i call the login() class and use the AJAX data

```
<?php
require 'classuser.php';

$usuario = $_POST["user"];
$contraseña = $_POST["pass"];
echo $usuario;
$logeo=new Users($usuario, $contraseña);
$logeo->login();

?>
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around `$this->user` and `$this->pass` in your query `$sql = "SELECT * from user where username = ".$this->user." and password = ".$this->pass;`

Comment: @Nick I used the quotes that way, but it still doesn´t work $sql = "SELECT * from user where username = '".$this->user."' and password = '".$this->pass"'";

Comment: If that's the exact code you used you're missing a `.` between `->pass` and `"`

Comment: because you're using ajax. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851860/6607392

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP header() called via AJAX not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851792/php-header-called-via-ajax-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.  It looks like you are echoing your mysqli errors prior to starting your session.  You session has to be set before anything gets outputted to the browser.

Here are my suggestions to fix your problem.

1. You Users class should not have anything in the file except the class. ie. No requires or session_starts().
2. In your case the `Users` class should extend the `Conexion` class.
3. Your `session_start()` should always be the first line in the initial PHP script. In your case the logeo.php script.

logeo.php

```
<?php
session_start();  //Always first line.  Has to be set before anything is sent out to the browser.

require 'bdcon.php';
require 'classuser.php';

$usuario = $_POST["user"];
$contraseña = $_POST["pass"];
echo $usuario;
$logeo=new Users($usuario, $contraseña);
$logeo->login();

?>
```

classuser.php

```
class Users extends Conexion
{
   public $user;
   public $pass;

   public function __construct($usuario, $contraseña)
   {
       $this->user=$usuario;
       $this->pass=$contraseña;
   }
   public function login()
   {
        $db = new Conexion(); //By extending the class you would not need to make a new instance of the Conexion class.

    $sql = "SELECT * from user where username = ".$this->user." and password = ".$this->pass;                       

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); ////By extending your class this could be something like "$this->db->prepare($sql);"
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($count == 1 && !empty($row)){
        $_SESSION["USERNAME"] = $row["username"];
        header('location: directivo.php');
    }else{
        echo"Error";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

That should get you going in the right direction.  You may have to tinker around with your `Conexion` class to get it to work correctly.